# Apache Kafka : Unable to setup clusters in Linux environment

Tags: apache-kafka

I tried to setup a cluster environment in kafka in two different Linux boxes, however not able to do it. Can someone please help me.

For two Linux boxes, didn't change any modification of default zookeeper.properties file. However changed the server.properties in config folder in kafka root directory.

```
linux box 1 : server.properties

broker.id=1 port=9092 zookeeper.connect=server1:9092,server2:9092

linux box 2 : server.properties

broker.id=1 port=9092 zookeeper.connect=server1:9092,server2:9092
```

In zookeeper.connect even i also tried to give as zookeeper.connect=server1:2181,server2:2181 but not luck.

Can anyone point me where I get how to configure Kafka in multiple boxes or else suggest me where i am doing wrong

Thanks, bhimesh

Comment: try as @Hussain Pirosha mentioned , the broker id must be unique across the cluster  and the `zookeeper` port is by default set to `2181` .. make the id unique and try

Answer (score 1):

`broker.id` should be unique for each kafka broker. In your case, both the brokers have the same  value. Correct that first and try.

Comment: No luck yet. I missing some basic configuration in multiple cluster enviornment, any other suggestions plz.

Comment: could you please post the config files and some exception logs

Comment: Problem got resolved, in Kafka documentation they didn't specify how to configure cluster environment.

Need to specify in the zookeeper.properties all the server details other than the default properties comes under kafka distribution.

Under zookeeper.properties file

Ex :  server.1 = hostname1:1000:3000 ( ports listening from 1000 to 3000)
      server.2 = hostname2:1000:3000 

and also provide the below properties 

tickTime=2000
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2